# How to do explicit resize?

Tags: verilog

Is there a way to do explicit resize to `LEN` of an expression?

The reason I want this is to make the code explicitly describe the intention and also to avoid the warnings for implicit resize that some tools generate.

The code below works in some tools, but fails in others:

```
localparam EXPR = 12;
localparam LEN = 7;
assign res = LEN'(EXPR);
```

Based on reading the Verilog-2001 standard, it looks like length by `LEN'...` can only be used for literals, e.g. `7'd12`, and not for general expressions.

Is there a way to do explicit resize of general expressions in Verilog-2001?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is already in SystemVerilog. You need to make sure you turn it on or use the proper .sv file extension so your tools recognize it.

```
assign res = LEN'(EXPR);
```

However, there is no way to dynamically calculate the length of a type - it needs to be a constant expression.

But you can dynamically apply a mask that truncates your value to desired length

```
assign res = EXPR & ((64'b10<<LEN)-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
localparam LEN = 7;
localparam [LEN-1:0] EXPR = 12;
assign res = EXPR;
```

or if you need to use `EXPR` for some other purpose

```
localparam LEN = 7;
localparam [LEN-1:0] EXPR7 = 12;
localparam EXPR = 12;
assign res = EXPR7
```

Comment: Thanks, I see it addresses the example code.  However, what I am looking for is some general way of resizing an expression, to change any expression `expr` that could be constant or calculated based on wires, to have the length `LEN`, as if doing `LEN'(expr)`.  Is that possible?

Comment: Well, you can always make something smaller using a part-select: `narrow = wide[N-1:0];` Making something bigger is a bit more tricky, because it depends whether it is signed or unsigned. How about asking another question that makes it clear what you're asking and then I or someone else can answer that. (It would be better not to edit this question because assuming it is not a duplicate, there is some useful info in this question and answer for the hypothetical future Googler that we're all supposed to be providing a service for.)

Comment: OK, thanks.  Yes, I won't edit this question to clarify.  However, based on what I have found so far, I am pretty sure that there is no explicit resize operfation in Verilog, since it generally applies implicit resize, and that is considered smart.  That the tools generate warnings about such implicit resize is just an inconvenient side effect.

Answer (score 0):

System Verilog has a $bits() system call. It returns the number of bits required for an expression. Thus:

```
wire [11:0] res;
$bits(res) // <= will return 12
```

You have to check if you simulator/compiler supports it. Also I don't know if you can use it as:

```
$bits(res)'d7
```

The only thing I should warn off is not to sacrifice your code readability to suppress superfluous warnings. Good readability prevents more errors than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have a [systemverilog] macro I use for resizing:

```
// Drive a signal with a constant, automatically resize constant to signal value
`define assign_const(SIGNAL,VALUE) assign SIGNAL = ($bits(SIGNAL))'(VALUE)
```

The `($bits(SIGNAL))'(VALUE)` is the critical part. It uses $bits to determine the signal length and recasts the value accordingly.

Comment: Better to add a tag of the technology that you are using for more responses . https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging